# Custom Class Level Validation - Creating the Annotation

Tags: java, validation, customvalidator

I want to implement a custom validator in a Spring Boot v1.5.14.RELEASE app. First I create a custom constraint annotation:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public interface CreateBook {
}
```

However, I receive this compilation error:

```
@Retention not applicable to type
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `public @interface CreateBook` instead of `public interface CreateBook`?

Comment: true @Amongalen, please convert to answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with how you define a new annotation. It should be like this:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CreateBook {
}
```

Note the `@` character in `@interface`